# Creating A Deck Of Cards In R Without Using While And Double For Loop

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I am creating a blackjack simulator in R.  The code below succeeds in creating the deck(s) of cards that I want.  (For those that play, I will deal with the value of an Ace later).

My question is, is there a better way to create the deck that doesn't involve a while loop plus a double for loop?  I have more of an issue with the double for loop.  The while loop is likely unavoidable since the number of decks created is variable.

I also initialize an empty data frame which I know isn't the best practice, however, the data set is so small in this case that it won't effect performance.

And lastly, is there an equivalent of i++ in R?  I have been programming in java as well and have gotten used to it.

Thanks.

```
createDeck <- function(totalNumOfDecks = 2)
{
  suits <- c("Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades")
  cards <- c("Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four","Five", 
             "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
             "Jack", "Queen", "King")
  values <- c(0,2,3,4,5,
              6,7,8,9,10,
              10,10,10)

  deck <- data.frame(Suit=character(0), Card=character(0), Value=numeric(0))

  numOfDecks = 1

  while (numOfDecks <= totalNumOfDecks){
    for (i in suits){
      for (j in cards){
        deck <- rbind.data.frame(deck, cbind.data.frame(j, i, values[match(j, cards)]))
      }
    }
    numOfDecks = numOfDecks + 1
  }

  print(deck)
}
```

Comment: See `?expand.grid`. But frankly, it would probably be easier to just use a single factor with 52 levels.

Comment: If josilber's method for creating N decks with characterstrings works for you, then let me just suggest that, since presumably you're going to want to shuffle your cards at some point, that you create a "shuffler" something like `cardorder<-sample(1:(N*52),N*52)` and use the resulting vector to re-order the `deck` rows.

Comment: ...just to expand on my comment: what I meant was that I would probably just use a integer vector 0:51 for the cards and then use modular arithmetic to determine suit and rank, and indexing of another vector to determine value. That would probably be much, much faster than pushing data.frame's around.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I wasn't going to shuffle, rather, I would remove one card at random.

Comment: @joran I am interested in your idea, but how would modular arithmetic help in this case?  I can't make the connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `expand.grid` function should be helpful:

```
# Define suits, cards, values
suits <- c("Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades")
cards <- c("Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four","Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
values <- c(0, 2:9, rep(10, 4))
totalNumOfDecks <- 2

# Build deck, replicated proper number of times
deck <- expand.grid(cards=cards, suits=suits)
deck$value <- values
deck <- deck[rep(seq(nrow(deck)), totalNumOfDecks),]
```

The call to `expand.grid` computes all pairing of cards and suits. The `value` variable is created by recycling the `value` vector for each suit. Finally, `rep(seq(nrow(deck)))` repeats rows 1-52 the proper number of times to get multiple copies of your deck.

Answer (score 5):

This is related to my recent [`paste.grid`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35726616/paste-grid-expand-grid-for-string-concatenation) question; see there for some other options, including the straightforward `levels(interaction(...))` approach.

Just made a deck myself and it uses the unicode characters for the suits so it looks snazzy; here's what I did:

```
cards = c(2:10, "J", "Q", "K", "A")
suits = c("♠", "♥", "♦", "♣")
deck <- paste0(rep(cards, length(suits)),  #card values
               rep(suits, each = length(cards))) #suits
deck
#  [1] "2♠"  "3♠"  "4♠"  "5♠"  "6♠"  "7♠"  "8♠"  "9♠"  "10♠" "J♠"  "Q♠"  "K♠" 
# [13] "A♠"  "2♥"  "3♥"  "4♥"  "5♥"  "6♥"  "7♥"  "8♥"  "9♥"  "10♥" "J♥"  "Q♥" 
# [25] "K♥"  "A♥"  "2♦"  "3♦"  "4♦"  "5♦"  "6♦"  "7♦"  "8♦"  "9♦"  "10♦" "J♦" 
# [37] "Q♦"  "K♦"  "A♦"  "2♣"  "3♣"  "4♣"  "5♣"  "6♣"  "7♣"  "8♣"  "9♣"  "10♣"
# [49] "J♣"  "Q♣"  "K♣"  "A♣"
```

Answer (score 4):

If I had to simulate a deck (or multiple decks) I would probably prefer to use a single integer vector in conjunction with some reference vectors, and then simply use modular arithmetic and indexing to determine suit, rank and value.

```
#Setup
suits <- c('Clubs','Diamonds','Hearts','Spades')
card <- c('Ace','Two','Three','Four','Five',
                    'Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten',
                    'Jack','Queen','King')
value <- c(0,2:10,rep(10,3))
deck <- 0:51

#Full deck
suits[(deck %/% 13) + 1]
card[(deck %% 13) + 1]
value[(deck %% 13) + 1]

#Some random cards
hand <- sample(deck,5)
suits[(hand %/% 13) + 1]
card[(hand %% 13) + 1]
value[(hand %% 13) + 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
buildDeck <- function(noOfDecks=1){
    suits <- c("Clubs", "Spades", "Diamonds", "Hearts")
    cards <-c("Ace", 2:10, "Jack", "Queen", "King")
    Deck <- paste(cards, rep(suits, each=13), sep="-")
    d<-rep(Deck,noOfDecks) #Build decks
    shuffledDeck <-sample(d,length(d)) #Shuffle decks
    shuffledDeck
}
```