# paste grid -- expand.grid for string concatenation

Tags: r, combinations, string-concatenation

If we want to get all combinations of two vectors, we can use `rep`/recycling rules:

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 1:2

cbind(rep(x, each = length(y)), rep(y, length(x)))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    2
# [3,]    2    1
# [4,]    2    2
# [5,]    3    1
# [6,]    3    2
# [7,]    4    1
# [8,]    4    2
```

But `expand.grid` is much nicer -- it handles all the repetition for us.

```
expand.grid(x, y)
#   Var1 Var2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    1
# 3    3    1
# 4    4    1
# 5    1    2
# 6    2    2
# 7    3    2
# 8    4    2
```

Is there a simple version of this for concatenating strings? Like `paste.grid`? I have a named object where a lot of the objects have names like `x_y_z` where `x`, `y`, and `z` vary like `x` and `y` above.

For example, suppose `x` can be `"avg"` or `"median"`, `y` can be `"male"` or `"female"`, and `z` can be `"height"` or `"weight"`. How can we concisely get all 8 combinations of the three?

Using `rep` is a pain:

```
x <- c("avg", "median")
y <- c("male", "female")
z <- c("height", "weight")
paste(rep(x, each = length(y) * length(z)),
      rep(rep(y, each = length(z)), length(x)),
      rep(z, length(x) * length(y)), sep = "_")
```

And repurposing `expand.grid` is a bit clunky (and probably inefficient):

```
apply(expand.grid(x, y, z), 1, paste, collapse = "_")
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Having `Reduce` you could extend your binary function to more arguments: `Reduce(function(x, y) paste(rep(x, each = length(y)), rep(y, length(x)), sep = "_"), list(x, y, z))`. This, also, might save re-concatenating same elements more than once and could be efficient in some cases.

Comment: @alexis_laz oh wow, I actually just came up with the same function by examining the other answers. Please post as an answer because it's much faster than anything besides spelling out the `rep` sequence by hand.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is what `interaction` does

```
levels(interaction(x,y,z,sep='_'))
```

The implementation is pretty much the same as your `rep` code.

Outputs:

```
[1] "avg_female_height"    "median_female_height" "avg_male_height"      "median_male_height"   "avg_female_weight"   
[6] "median_female_weight" "avg_male_weight"      "median_male_weight"
```

Answer (score 8):

Using data.table's `CJ` cross-joining function:

```
library(data.table)
CJ(x,y,z)[, paste(V1,V2,V3, sep = "_")]
#[1] "avg_female_height"    "avg_female_weight"    "avg_male_height"      "avg_male_weight"     
#[5] "median_female_height" "median_female_weight" "median_male_height"   "median_male_weight"
```

Or a variation of your `apply` approach would be:

```
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(x, y, z), sep = "_"))
#[1] "avg_male_height"      "median_male_height"   "avg_female_height"    "median_female_height"
#[5] "avg_male_weight"      "median_male_weight"   "avg_female_weight"    "median_female_weight"
```

Comment: Nice. `do.call` can be used also in the `data.table` approach: `CJ(x,y,z)[, do.call(paste,c(.SD,sep="_"))]`, just to avoid to type all the column names.

Comment: Correct, @nicola. I had posted that too but then removed it since I think without it the data.table approach will be faster (but didn't test it). Feel free to add that to the answer since I can't currently do that myself.

Answer (score 5):

Rudimentary (`microbenchmark::microbenchmark`) benchmarking shows a pretty significant speed-up by using:

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

df <- data.frame(x, y, z)

df %>%
  complete(x, y, z) %>%
  unite("combo", x, y, z, sep = "_")
```

A bit slower, but perhaps more straight forward and vectorized variant the `apply` technique:

```
df <- expand.grid(x, y, z)
df$combo <- paste(df$Var1, df$Var1, df$Var3, sep = "_")
```

Someone should chime in with a `data.table` approach...

---

## Benchmarking: Small Grid (256 elements)

```
set.seed(21034)
x <- sample(letters, 4, TRUE)
y <- sample(letters, 4, TRUE)
z <- sample(letters, 4, TRUE)
a <- sample(letters, 4, TRUE)

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

microbenchmark(times = 25L,
               DT1 = CJ(x, y, z, a)[ , paste(V1, V2, V3, V4, sep = "_")],
               DT2 = CJ(x, y, z, a)[ , do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "_"))],
               app1 = do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(x, y, z, a), sep = "_")),
               app2 = paste((df <- expand.grid(x, y, z, a))$Var1,
                            df$Var2, df$Var3, sep = "_"),
               magg_outer = outer(x, y, paste, sep = "_") %>%
                 outer(z, paste, sep = "_") %>%
                 outer(a, paste, sep = "_") %>% as.vector,
               magg_tidy = data.frame(x, y, z, a) %>% 
                 complete(x, y, z, a) %>%
                 unite("combo", x, y, z, a, sep = "_"),
               interaction = levels(interaction(x, y, z, a, sep = "_")),
               original = apply(expand.grid(x, y, z, a), 1, paste, collapse = "_"),
               rep = paste(rep(x, each = (ny <- length(y)) * (nz <- length(z)) *
                                 (na <- length(a))),
                           rep(rep(y, each = nz * na), (nx <- length(x))),
                           rep(rep(z, each = na), nx * ny), sep = "_"),
               Reduce = Reduce(function(x, y) paste(rep(x, each = length(y)), 
                                                     rep(y, length(x)), sep = "_"), 
                               list(x, y, z, a)))

# Unit: microseconds
#         expr      min        lq       mean    median        uq       max neval    cld
#          DT1  529.578  576.6400  624.00002  589.8270  604.9845  5449.287  1000    d  
#          DT2  561.028  606.4220  639.94659  620.4335  636.2735  5484.514  1000    d  
#         app1  201.043  225.4475  240.36960  233.4795  243.7090  4244.687  1000  b    
#         app2  196.692  225.6130  244.33543  234.0455  243.7925  4110.605  1000  b    
#   magg_outer  164.352  194.1395  205.30300  204.4220  211.1990   456.122  1000  b    
#    magg_tidy 1872.228 2038.1560 2150.98234 2067.8770 2126.1025 21891.884  1000      f
#  interaction  254.885  295.1935  313.54392  306.6680  316.8095  4196.465  1000   c   
#     original  852.018  935.4960  976.24388  954.5115  972.5550  4973.724  1000     e 
#          rep   50.737   54.1515   60.22671   55.3660   56.9220  3823.655  1000 a     
#       Reduce   58.395   65.3860   68.46049   66.8920   68.5640   158.184  1000 a
```

## Benchmarking: Large Grid (1,000,000 elements)

```
set.seed(21034)
x <- sprintf("%03d", sample(100))
y <- sprintf("%03d", sample(100))
z <- sprintf("%02d", sample(10))
a <- sprintf("%02d", sample(10))

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

microbenchmark(times = 25L,
               DT1 = CJ(x, y, z, a)[ , paste(V1, V2, V3, V4, sep = "_")],
               DT2 = CJ(x, y, z, a)[ , do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = "_"))],
               app1 = do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(x, y, z, a), sep = "_")),
               app2 = paste((df <- expand.grid(x, y, z, a))$Var1,
                            df$Var2, df$Var3, sep = "_"),
               magg_outer = outer(x, y, paste, sep = "_") %>%
                 outer(z, paste, sep = "_") %>%
                 outer(a, paste, sep = "_") %>% as.vector,
               magg_tidy = data.frame(x, y, z, a) %>% 
                 complete(x, y, z, a) %>%
                 unite("combo", x, y, z, a, sep = "_"),
               interaction = levels(interaction(x, y, z, a, sep = "_")),
               original = apply(expand.grid(x, y, z, a), 1, paste, collapse = "_"),
               rep = paste(rep(x, each = (ny <- length(y)) * (nz <- length(z)) *
                                 (na <- length(a))),
                           rep(rep(y, each = nz * na), (nx <- length(x))),
                           rep(rep(z, each = na), nx * ny), sep = "_"),
               Reduce = Reduce(function(x, y) paste(rep(x, each = length(y)), 
                                                     rep(y, length(x)), sep = "_"), 
                               list(x, y, z, a)))

# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval  cld
#          DT1  360.6528  467.8408  517.4579  520.1484  549.1756  861.1567    25 ab  
#          DT2  355.0438  504.9642  572.0732  551.9106  615.6621  927.3210    25  b  
#         app1  727.4513  766.3053  926.1888  910.3998  957.7610 1690.1540    25   c 
#         app2  472.5724  567.1121  633.5304  600.3779  634.3158 1135.7535    25  b  
#   magg_outer  384.0112  475.5070  600.6317  525.8936  676.7134  927.6736    25  b  
#    magg_tidy  520.6428  602.5028  695.5500  680.8821  748.8746 1180.1107    25  bc 
#  interaction  353.7317  481.4732  531.0035  518.7084  585.0872  693.5171    25 ab  
#     original 4965.1156 5358.8704 5914.3560 5780.6609 6074.7470 9024.6476    25    d
#          rep  206.0964  236.5811  273.1093  252.8179  285.0910  455.1776    25 a   
#       Reduce  322.0695  390.2595  446.3948  424.9185  508.5235  621.1878    25 ab
```

Comment: So `magrittr` + `tidyr` scales _very_ well, but is junk for smaller samples. Seems like `interaction` is pretty robust and also looks pretty, so I think I'll award the check there. All of these answers are great though! Glad I asked this question.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Good deal. Thanks for the edit and a neat question.

Comment: Just realized why `interaction` does so well -- it iteratively deletes duplicated elements! so if `x = c("a", "a")` and `y = c("b", "b")`, all the other methods would return 4 elements, but `interaction` returns just 2. Updated to remove this unfair advantage and it seems `rep` is uniformly best.

Comment: Sounds like you need to give yourself the check :) How about abstracting it into a nice function? Or does the `Reduce` approach hold up?

Comment: Actually just arrived at the conclusion alexis came to hours ago! `Reduce` is indeed the most robust. About as fast as `Rep` on the smaller sample, but only about 25% faster than the others on the larger sample.

Answer (score 3):

What about using `outer()`? Your two examples become

```
x <- 1:4
y <- 1:2
as.vector(outer(x, y, paste, sep = "_"))
## [1] "1_1" "2_1" "3_1" "4_1" "1_2" "2_2" "3_2" "4_2"

library(magrittr)
x <- c("avg", "median")
y <- c("male", "female")
z <- c("height", "weight")
outer(x, y, paste, sep = "_") %>% outer(z, paste, sep = "_") %>% as.vector
## [1] "avg_male_height"      "median_male_height"   "avg_female_height"    "median_female_height" "avg_male_weight"     
## [6] "median_male_weight"   "avg_female_weight"    "median_female_weight"
```

The second example can be simplified a little with `Reduce()`:

```
Reduce(function(a, b) outer(a, b, paste, sep = "_"), list(x, y, z)) %>% as.vector
```

It's not efficient, however. Using `microbenchmark`, I find that your solution using `rep()` is about 10 times faster.

Comment: I'm impressed how well this did in the benchmarks actually! A bit messy to do with 3 or more inputs though.

Comment: Just turns out that for smaller examples, `rep` is by far the fastest approach (though perhaps also the clunkiest)