# Concatenate two vectors of strings with specific order

Tags: r

I would like to concatenate two vectors. I already know how to do it but there is only one problem - order.

So, I use a function below to link vectors but the output is not the one I would like to have:

```
var_names <- c("Tim", "Jack", "Tom")
var_tp<- c("0", "40", "-u")

vec <- paste(rep(var_names, 3), var_tp, sep="_")
```

Output:

```
> vec
[1] "Tim_0"   "Jack_40" "Tom_-u"  "Tim_0"   "Jack_40" "Tom_-u"  "Tim_0"   "Jack_40" "Tom_-u"
```

My desired output is to keep the order as it was in original vectors, prioritizing `names` over `tp`.

Desired output:

```
> vec
[1] "Tim_0"   "Tim_40" "Tim_-u"  "Jack_0"   "Jack_40" "Jack_-u"  "Tom_0"   "Tom_40" "Tom_-u"
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35726616/680068

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply by using each

```
vec <- paste(rep(var_names, each=3), var_tp, sep="_")
[1] "Tim_0"   "Tim_40"  "Tim_-u"  "Jack_0"  "Jack_40" "Jack_-u" "Tom_0"   "Tom_40"  "Tom_-u"
```

Comment: I just used `help(rep)` and also figured it out at the same time. I was too fast with asking a question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `outer`

```
vec <- c(t(outer(var_names,var_tp,paste, sep = "_")))
```

such that

```
> vec
[1] "Tim_0"   "Tim_40"  "Tim_-u"  "Jack_0"  "Jack_40" "Jack_-u"
[7] "Tom_0"   "Tom_40"  "Tom_-u"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another option could be:

```
unlist(lapply(var_names, paste, sep = "_", var_tp))

[1] "Tim_0"   "Tim_40"  "Tim_-u"  "Jack_0"  "Jack_40" "Jack_-u" "Tom_0"   "Tom_40" 
[9] "Tom_-u"
```