# Repeatedly shuffling a deck of cards in R

Tags: r, random, random-seed

I have a problem with writing a code labyrinth, which will repeatedly shuffle the deck of cards. I have a line written that shuffles my waist, but each time the deck is shuffled in the same way. I need help writing the code so that each time the cards are shuffled in a different way.

```
shuffling <-sample(deck,length(deck))
```

Comment: Are you doing this in loop (maybe parallel loop)? I guess that seed gets reset to the same value or you're overwriting result and getting last call from the loop. Also, you don't need to pass `length(deck)`, `sample(deck)` is enough.

Comment: If you've looping, try to use the loop index `i` for seed: `for(i in 1:n){set.seed(i);
shuffling <- sample(deck); ...}` (`;` instead of newline, as this is a comment)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a base R solution that generates a vector of seeds and 10 samples from a group of 10 cards.

```
seeds <- runif(10)*1000000
cards <- 1:10

shuffledDecks <- lapply(seeds,function(aSeed){
     set.seed(aSeed)
     sample(cards)
})
```

When we inspect the list in the RStudio object viewer, we see that all the card orders in the 10 shuffles are different.

[image]

If we apply one of the approaches to create a card deck from [Creating a Deck of Cards Without Using While and Double For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685024/creating-a-deck-of-cards-in-r-without-using-while-and-double-for-loop?rq=1), a set of 10 shuffles of a deck of 52 playing cards looks like this.

```
seeds <- runif(10)*1000000
cards = c(2:10, "J", "Q", "K", "A")
suits = c("♠", "♥", "♦", "♣")
deck <- paste0(rep(cards, length(suits)),  #card values
               rep(suits, each = length(cards))) #suits

shuffledDecks <- lapply(seeds,function(aSeed){
     set.seed(aSeed)
     sample(deck)
})

shuffledDecks[[1]]
shuffledDecks[[2]]
```

...and the output:

```
> shuffledDecks[[1]]
 [1] "3♥"  "Q♠"  "6♦"  "8♠"  "9♠"  "2♦"  "10♥" "J♥"  "7♦"  "6♣"  "7♠"  "3♣"  "2♠"  "8♦"  "8♥"  "A♦"  "10♣" "A♥"  "5♦"  "J♦" 
[21] "A♠"  "4♥"  "7♣"  "4♣"  "3♠"  "6♠"  "5♥"  "K♠"  "5♣"  "5♠"  "J♣"  "6♥"  "9♥"  "K♣"  "Q♥"  "9♣"  "A♣"  "9♦"  "3♦"  "K♦" 
[41] "4♦"  "J♠"  "4♠"  "8♣"  "10♠" "Q♦"  "Q♣"  "K♥"  "7♥"  "2♣"  "2♥"  "10♦"
> shuffledDecks[[2]]
 [1] "7♠"  "5♦"  "6♥"  "Q♣"  "K♥"  "J♦"  "Q♠"  "Q♥"  "3♦"  "4♥"  "2♦"  "A♠"  "9♦"  "4♣"  "7♣"  "8♦"  "4♠"  "5♠"  "K♦"  "3♥" 
[21] "6♣"  "A♣"  "10♥" "8♠"  "8♣"  "J♣"  "J♠"  "10♦" "7♦"  "5♣"  "10♣" "9♣"  "K♣"  "K♠"  "8♥"  "6♠"  "2♠"  "5♥"  "3♣"  "J♥" 
[41] "A♦"  "3♠"  "4♦"  "9♥"  "A♥"  "6♦"  "9♠"  "7♥"  "2♥"  "10♠" "2♣"  "Q♦" 
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set the random generator seed as the current time expressed in seconds (or in milliseconds if that's not enough, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40059573/3871924)). This way, everytime you do the sampling, it will be a new generator seed.

```
cards = c(1:10, "J", "Q", "K", "A")
set.seed(as.numeric(Sys.time()))
sample(cards)
####  [1] "3"  "2"  "10" "6"  "J"  "4"  "7"  "5"...
```